# Tracing support in gRPC on C++

Tags: c++, grpc

I found some old threads claiming that C++ is not supported, but no recent information.

Is there any way to do tracing on gRPC with C++?

Comment: I believe gRPC supports c++ -- https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/cpp/

Comment: @Xilpex Could you be more specific? Where exactly does it talk about tracing?

Comment: @ŠimonTóth: This GitHub [issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/12707) talks about this that it depends on the interceptors functionality which leads to this [issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9035). The interceptors' functionality seems to be implemented and merged. See this [commit](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/7bf82de9eda0aa8fecfe5edb33834f1b272be30b/test/cpp/end2end/server_interceptors_end2end_test.cc). Maybe, the next step would be the tracing support. I guess the best place to look for would be the GitHub repo and its issues.

Comment: The developer who created: https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/cpp-grpc, is working on: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-cpp, which might be the next step for tracing support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of research this is what seems to be true as of April 25th 2020:

1. The framework of choice is OpenCensus, it supports both tracing and metrics
2. OpenTelemetry will be replacing OpenCensus at some point, but is not ready for C++
3. OpenCensus for C++ is not perfect, it mostly works, but is missing some features available in other languages (e.g. metric for number of RPCs)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it seems like [this](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-cpp) is the solution.

The instructions are [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc.io/blob/master/content/docs/quickstart/cpp.md) as well as [here](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/cpp/)